# How to convert mongoDB data into arff file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, weka, mean-stack, arff

I have different data set from users through different forms. I am using MEAN stack, mongoose and node-weka to analyze stored data, but before that, weka uses arff files, that is why I have to convert data stored in mongoDB into ARFF file. does anyone know how to do it? I am a beginner and I haven't found the right documents. 
Here is the beginning of the code in NODE JS

```
var data = ... //ARFF json format
var options = {
 //'classifier': 'weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes', 
 'classifier': 'weka.classifiers.functions.SMO',
    'params'    : ''
       };
 var testData = {
     outlook    : 'sunny',
      windy      : 'TRUE'
          };

       weka.classify(data, testData, options, function (err, result) {

     console.log(result); //{ predicted: 'yes', prediction: '1' }
```

Comment: if anyone interessed, it is the way to convert into json file pawn('mongoexport', [ '--db', 'test', '--collection', 'users', '--out', 'file.json' ])
.on('error', function( err ){ throw err });

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a pure-javascript solution, only about a command-line solution (for linux, unix and mac).

In any case, many of weka's classifiers indeed expect an arff file as input.

You can export your json data to csv, convert csv to .arff on-the-fly on the command line, and then pipe them to weka 3.6 (not 3.7).

You can use a bash script  to convert csv  to arff via a tempfile. This special-purpose script `weka-cluster` demonstrates. Adapt it to your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ALGO="$@"
IN=$(mktemp --tmpdir weka-cluster-XXXXXXXX).arff

finish () {
    rm -f $IN
}
trap finish EXIT

csv2arff > $IN
weka filters.unsupervised.attribute.AddCluster -W "weka.${ALGO}" -i $IN -o /dev/stdout | arff2csv
```

call this script as

`cat my.csv | weka-cluster clusterers.SimpleKMeans`

you can extend this to mongodb, like this:

`mymongoquery.sh | json2csv | (more optional filters.e.g csvcut) | weka-cluster clusterers.SimpleKMeans`

These command-line tools (but not mongo) are described in more detail in the book "[Data science  the command line](http://datascienceatthecommandline.com/#tools)" by Jeroen Janssen.  Check out the [github repo](https://github.com/jeroenjanssens/data-science-at-the-command-line) for csv2arff, weka-cluster, and on how to install the other tools (csv2arff, arff2csv, csvcut, json2csv).